# Flash AS3 : HitTest unexpected error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

If have a Problem with this bit of code in my Flash AS3 Project:

```
//Hit Test between Objects
function hitTest(a,b:DisplayObject):Boolean {
    if (b.hitTestObject(a) == true) then {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am calling it like so:

```
trace(hitTest(player, c_lvl.gold1));
```

Player is an Object created in my Code (instance of a movieclip):

```
player = new Player();
world.addChild(player);
```

gold1 is an instance of a movieclip packed in another movieclip called c_lvl.

Im getting 2 errors:

```
/Users/nicolasbrauch/Google Drive/info_1/script.as, Line 141    1008: Attribute is invalid.
/Users/nicolasbrauch/Google Drive/info_1/script.as, Line 143    1083: Syntax error: else is unexpected.
```

Line 141 is the first Line of my hitTest function.

What shall I do? Where is my error? I dont get it...

Comment: There is no `then` in `if` statement in AS. For more information about `if` statement, take a look here : [Adobe.com : if](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#if).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As akmozo said, you shouldn't have a `then` keyword after your `if` conditional. Once you remove that keyword, you will have fixed both errors.